# Unable to uninstall programs using sudo pip

Tags: pip

I looked this up online but they're all suggesting using sudo command
I used

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

I get this message:

```
Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
```

I installed it using pip , not apt .

The output of :

```
 $ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
 python-numpy: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
```

PS: I'm a mac user, I usually use homebrew for my installations, so I'm an amateur in Ubuntu

Comment: did you install it using `sudo pip install numpy` or using `pip install numpy`?

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy` please.

Comment: using sudo pip install numpy

Answer (score 23):

According to the output of `dpkg -S`, `numpy` has been installed using `apt` to remove it run:

```
sudo apt remove python-numpy
```

you might have a local installation of it using `pip`, to remve that you can use:

```
pip uninstall numpy --user
```

Comment: Wouldn't pip remove numpy --user make a clash with pip of miniconda2?

Comment: As far as I know, no... miniconda environment is separate from pip.

Comment: I uninstalled it using `sudo apt`, however when I run `sudo pip list` I still get numpy in the list .

Comment: Now try removing it using `sudo pip remove numpy`, it should work now.

Comment: Addition when I used  `pip remove numpy --user` I got  `ERROR: unknown command "remove" `

Comment: My bad, use `uninstall` instead of `remove`: `sudo pip uninstall numpy` and `pip uninstall numpy --user`

Comment: I'm getting `no such option: --user` . Perhaps it's in the pip version?  The computer I'm working on has a pip version of 8.1.1

Comment: It might be, update it: `sudo pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: There is no `--user` option, even after updating. However, `--isolated` worked.

Answer (score 4):

use `--isolated` option.

like below:

`sudo pip uninstall numpy --isolated`

Answer (score 4):

Only this above tip helped:

```
sudo apt remove python3-numpy
```

->

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-jquery-ui python-matplotlib-data python3-kiwisolver
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-matplotlib python3-numpy
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 28.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 389330 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3-matplotlib (3.1.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Removing python3-numpy (1:1.17.4-5ubuntu3) ...
```

and then reinstalling as a user:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: Although I never install python packages via apt, it seems to me this answer helps with packages installed under an old distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try running with sudo but passing the python path in the command:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/ pip uninstall numpy -y
```

I was having trouble to uninstall some packages due to a lack of permission

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/usr/local/bin/runlike'

and when inserting sudo in the command, it was looking for python packages in the wrong directory.

Another tip is to make sure if you're using pip or pip3 !

To check if something is still in the machine, run

```
dpkg -l | grep python
```

And uninstall any package you see is still there using apt

```
sudo apt remove python-nympy
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I sovled the problem by editing `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and manually removing the two directories associated with numpy.

After that I reinstalled the packages using

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it when I deleted a file to which I had given the name `numpy.py`.

Comment: "*I solved it when I deleted a file*" is really not a helpful answer to others unless you explain what file needed to be deleted along with the file path.  You should consider editing your answer to make sure that it offers a solution that others can apply.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with tartube package and it is a python package, I tried hard to remove that package but it always seems like it is not found, but I finally find a perfect solution and I hope it will be useful for you.

1. First I searched for the package using this command:

   `$ dpkg -l | grep python`
2. Then I found the python- followed by package name:
   [Search result of python packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO4FA.png)

   ii  python3-tartube    2.3.332-1  all   GUI front-end for youtube-dl
3. Then I used the dpkg with superuser privilege to remove it using this
   command:

   `sudo dpkg --remove python3-tartube`

- I hope this will be useful, also I want to share a picture of numpy, it's
  found on the pyhton package search
  [numpy search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOoGz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with juypter notebooks. Turns out that i had it installed globally and when i ran `jupyter` it was calling the global one instead of the one in the environment (or didn't instal into the venv coz it thought it was already installed, or something). So

1. uninstalling it outside the the venv
2. activate the venv and installing
   worked for me