# Can't boot into Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, blacklist

While trying to upgrade python, I've somehow managed to damage something in my Ubuntu setup. I first noticed that the terminal app had disappeared, and using ctrl-alt-Fx wouldn't give me a command line to reinstall it.

I then tried rebooting, but now it won't boot to GUI. I can log in and use the command line, but I have no network access so trying to reinstall ubuntu-desktop fails.

I've tried fixing the packages in recovery mode, and running boot-repair off USB, but neither of these have helped.

I do get a couple of warnings before it fails:

```
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
usb 5.1.4: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVB control 5 on unit 1: 0 (exp.1 )
usb 5.1.4: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVB control 5 on unit 1: 0 (exp.1 )
```

The blacklist error seems to suggest something to do with UEFI/BIOS, but this has not changed since I got the motherboard and the PC's been working fine for several years.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I can try before I resort to reinstalling?

Many thanks

Comment: Upgrading default python leads to a ruined system ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after uninstalling python](https://askubuntu.com/q/1326117/)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it booting again using the steps described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1341494/499631). A few funny quirks but at least I have a GUI to work with. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that when you link to another answer, that means that your question should simply be marked as a duplicate of the other question.  There's nothing wrong with duplicates, and they can actually be useful signposts for others searching for the same problem (with different search terms).  But rather than create an answer linking to the other question/answer, you should click the "Flag" option on your question and then flag it as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: As a side-note, would you let me know if you *don't* see the Flag option?  It should be near the "Edit" option under your question, but there seems to be some confusion as to whether or not it appears for users with less than 20 rep on their own questions.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds , I've flagged it as a duplicate but I think it needs to be approved first (likely due to my rep). I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: It seems to have worked - It might have just taken the Community Bot a few minutes to get around to processing it.  If you look in your [profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/499631/biglam?tab=topactivity), under the "Impact" callout, you'll see that you now have 1 helpful flag.  You also received the [Citizen Patrol](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge.  Congratulation! ;-)