# Ubuntu won't boot up after removing libpython3.8-stdlib

Tags: boot, package-management

Yesterday I was trying to install `psycopg2` on my laptop but it wouldn't install. It complained about broken packages and about `libpython3.8-stdlib`.

I decided to remove the package and to reinstall Python. So I found this on [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package):

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libpython3.8-stdlib
```

I reinstalled Python3.8 and Pip after that and everything seemed fine. I could install `psycopg2` after that. This morning I tried to boot up my laptop and it won't go past the HP logo.

I can get into recovery mode. Which packages do I have to install to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all traces of python from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321421/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-python-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This post here from Raffa saved my computer:
[How to remove all traces of python from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321421/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-python-from-ubuntu)

I tried installing all the packages and a lot of the packages were gone. Ubuntu boots up again