# Error message on the startup after installing PIP and updating Python

Tags: python

After installing PIP and updating Python to it's latest version, I got an error message about the Path and decided to fix it but it seems that what I did really didn't solve anything about the problem.
What is the standard procedure for adding a "Path" for a Python installation? pls help :(
This is the error that appears on the startup:

```
Error found when loading /home/maverick/.profile:

/home/maverick/.profile: line 28: :/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lo cal/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory

/home/maverick/.profile: line 29: :/home/maverick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sb in:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory

/home/maverick/.profile: line 30: :/home/maverick/.local/bin:/home/maverick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/ bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

**As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.**

That's basically the message so I don't really know how to fix or where to start.

Comment: How did you install Python and PIP? Replacing the system python may destroy Ubuntu

Comment: Also it would help resolving the issue if you posted the error message.

Comment: I'll try to take a picture of it, because it appears in a windows on startup not in the moment of execution of a code.

Comment: Don't change the default python version. Instead, use a virtual environment. If you change the default python version, many system apps will not work, and you will have to reinstall Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

> After installing PIP

That is most likely not an issue.

> and updating Python to it's latest version,

That is a big issue (*If you replace the default system Python version*) ... You don't do that ... Python should only be updated by your package-manager when you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release for major version updates and with usual Ubuntu security updates for minor versions.

The reason is (*As far as system Python goes*) that Ubuntu [relies heavily on Python](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321433) for system functionality and for that the [Python version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448819) is critical.

> I got an error message about the Path and decided to fix it but it
> seems that what I did really didn't solve anything about the problem.

You need to edit `/home/maverick/.profile` like so:

```
nano /home/maverick/.profile
```

Then comment out(*by adding `#` before them*) those lines(*number 28,29 and 30*) like so:

```
# :/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lo cal/games:/snap/bin:
# :/home/maverick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sb in:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
# :/home/maverick/.local/bin:/home/maverick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/ bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
```

Then, save the edit to the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd>.

Those lines appear to be remnants of broken old paths strings that were looking something like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lo cal/games:/snap/bin"
```

Where they were added to the environment variable `$PATH` and exported with `export` so that they will be available to other shells other than the parent shell and parsed as multiple search paths separated by colons `:`.

Now they are broken, your shell interprets them as paths to actual files and directories but with the added `:` and the whole line as a single path as well.

> What is the standard procedure for adding a "Path" for a Python
> installation?

The `PATH` environment variable (*set as such in a per user session*) is essential to the functionality of your userspace applications and is already set to something like this:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

To set it, make sure you preserve the search paths it already has by adding `$PATH:` at the beginning separating it from the additional paths with a colon `:` and separating the rest of additional paths by colons as well like so:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/additional/path/one:/additional/path/two:/additional/path/three"
```